# XSLT: Start Date & End Date

Tags: xml, xslt

How would I need to write the `XSL` code for one employee applying time off from `01/01/2017` to `10/02/017`.
I want the output to be like

```
Start date : 01/01/2017 and 
End date   : 10/02/2017
```

My output file is:

```
Employee id               Start Date                  End Date
123456                    01/01/2017                  01/10/2017
```

But I want it like this:

I am getting like

```
Employee id          Start Date             End Date

123456                01/01/2017            01/01/2017
123456                02/01/2017            02/01/2017
123456                03/01/2017            03/01/2017

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
123456                10/01/2017           10/01/2017
```

Please help how to write XSL logic

Comment: Please add your XML and the XSLT that you have written till now.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Please show the input (as XML code), and the expected output, also as code. Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. And clarify what date format you're using - currently you have a mixture of DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY.